# trouble adding jquery to webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, vue.js

i am new to webpack. i got installed through https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli 
I donl't quite understand how to add jquery dependency. i have tried just about every tutorial i could find and nothing seems to work.

I am using bootstrap and it keeps outputting a console error bootstrap requires Jquery.

in my node_modules/ folder i have Jquery there.

I don't exactly understand where the entry point is for the project. I believe it is packages.json so i will start there

in my scripts portion i have

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.18",
    "vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1"
  },
```

then if i am reading this correctly inder 'dev' mode i have build/dev-server.js as an entry point.

```
require('./check-versions')()
var config = require('../config')
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) process.env.NODE_ENV = JSON.parse(config.dev.env.NODE_ENV)
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var opn = require('opn')
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.dev.conf')
```

In that block of code i have tried adding `var jquery = require('jquery')` but that did not solve the issue.

then the next port of entry i believe is the webpack base.

which i have

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var utils = require('./utils')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
var webpack = require('webpack');

var jquery = require("jquery");

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV
// check env & config/index.js to decide whether to enable CSS source maps for the
// various preprocessor loaders added to vue-loader at the end of this file
var cssSourceMapDev = (env === 'development' && config.dev.cssSourceMap)
var cssSourceMapProd = (env === 'production' && config.build.productionSourceMap)
var useCssSourceMap = cssSourceMapDev || cssSourceMapProd

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|min.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
         test: require.resolve("jquery"),
         loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({ sourceMap: useCssSourceMap }),
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

which i have tried adding the require at the top , as well as the resolve alias, and the plugin for jquery which i all got from other tutorials. But nothing seems to work. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `step 5` of the [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html) docs seems like what you're looking for. You should just need to import it from your app's entry point. Also that's a pretty large webpack base.

Comment: thats basically the default one aside from anything jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in `webpack.base.conf.js`

Before module exports `var webpack = require('webpack')`
As well as:

```
resolve:{
 //other code
 plugins:[
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: "jquery",
   jQuery:'jquery',
   jquery:'jquery'
  }),
 ],
//other code
}
```

Make sure you install jquery via `npm install jquery` with the specific version you need. The code above will place the 3 names under the window object and you will have access to jquery globally as if you imported it as a script tag.